# Should the way NSAssert are handle be raised as a bug

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, macros

I have a couple of time been caught out putting function code in NSAssert or NSParameter assert, like

```
NSParameterAssert( [self doSomeWork] );
```

The problem with this is when you do a release build not only does the code that does an abort if the test fails get omitted from the code, but my code within the () is also omitted also.

Obviously this fix is simple but to me it still this seems wrong, the logic of the code is changed between test build and release build.

I should make it clear I only use this pattern for situation where if the assert fail it is a programmer error.

Comment: Just to make it clear, I'm asking if I should raise this as a bug with Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I prefer the AssertMacros, which guarantee that the code will be executed, but don't use assertions.

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/EXTERNAL_HEADERS/AssertMacros.h

Answer (score 0):

I use both assert and NSAssert, and so define the appropriate values to disable them in Distribution builds (I also normally work with a configuration ReleaseWithAsserts to get optimized code with the asserts enabled, so testing as close to the actual distributed code as possible).

What I do is this (you can use the other define if you want NDEBUG is for assert()):

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
BOOL didWorkSucceed = 
#endif
[self doSomeWork]; // returns a BOOL if succeeds

assert(didWorkSucceed);
```

You can use the defines for all kinds of stuff too - logging etc. Mostly I do test the return codes in Distribution, and return a nil object if it fails instead of ignoring it.